# How to "break" a Observable and jump to another page in Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, observable, angular2-observables

sorry for the confusing question. So currently i'm working with this block of code in Ionic, it looks like this:

home.ts :

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.myFunction().subscribe()( data => {

        // Do some stuff here, then 
        // open another page/modal with the data received

        this.openModal(anotherPage,data);
    }
}
```

The problem, I believe, is that I have to do something to "unsubscribe" my current function since it's being called every second. I tried putting the whole code in the **ionViewDidLoad**, believing that when it jumps to another page the function will be suspended but it just doesn;t work.

```
openModal(zone) {
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ZonePage, { 'zone': zone });
    modal.present();
  }
```

Any idea to solve this situation?

Comment: what does `openPage` do? is it only calling `navctrl.push`?

Comment: oops, sorry, I just edit the question

Comment: openPage or openModal? I think you pasted the wrong function here..

Comment: Just edit it again :( Sorry it's Modal, not page.

Comment: why not just unsubscribe at the end of the function?

Comment: So you mean to put : **this.events.unsubscribe('myFunction');** at the end of the **openModal()** ?

Comment: No... you are not using ionic events right? this is an observable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular/RxJs When should I unsubscribe from \`Subscription\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription)

Comment: alright I 'll take a look. Thanks for being so patient!

Answer (score 1):

one solution could be:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    let sub = this.myFunction().subscribe( data => {
        // Do some stuff here, then 
        // open another page/modal with the data received
        sub.unsubscribe();
        this.openModal(anotherPage,data);
    }
}
```

another one (when you know how often it emits before it you trigger your modal):

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.myFunction().take(10).subscribe( data => {
        // Do some stuff here, then 
        // open another page/modal with the data received
        this.openModal(anotherPage,data);
    }
}
```